# Stockfish JavaScript/HTML how get score in stockfish.js

Tags: javascript, html, stockfish

**This JavaScript/HTML Source Code**

**I** have a problem where I actually don't know how to retrieve the commands in the **stockfish.js** output because I have tried to manipulate the ***nmurgg*** code to the code I get, so the problem is:

```
myFunctions.loadChessEngine = function() {
        if(!stockfishObjectURL) {
            stockfishObjectURL = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([GM_getResourceText('stockfish.js')], {type: 'application/javascript'}));
        }
        console.log(stockfishObjectURL);
        if(stockfishObjectURL) {
            engine.engine = new Worker(stockfishObjectURL);

            engine.engine.onmessage = e => {
                parser(e);
            };
            engine.engine.onerror = e => {
                console.log("Worker Error: "+e);
            };

            engine.engine.postMessage('ucinewgame');
        }
        console.log('loaded chess engine');
    }
```

---

And This is the code that makes my head spin

```
function parser(e){

        if(e.data.includes('bestmove')){

            console.log(e.data.split(' ')[3]);

            myFunctions.color(e.data.split(' ')[1]);

            isThinking = false;

        }

    }
```

If I delete 'bestmove'

Then it will output all the information along with score, pv, steps, but if I don't delete 'bestmove', it outputs two words "BESTMOVE and PONDER"

I actually want to add a new command, which is to get "score cp" or things that need to be taken from the information, but I have done it like the nrumgg github that he made, it doesn't work in the existing script.

Is there anyone who can help me make the addition.

Like

Score Cp = Score

for me to see the results of the stockfish movement every step taken.

Thank you if you can help m
e.